# android logging sdcard

Tags: android, logging, android-emulator, sd-card

With Android-Emulator I am not able to write/create a file on the SD Card (for logging).
 Here is what I have done so far
- Run mksdcard 8192K C:\android-dev\emu_sdcard\emu_logFile
- Create a new AVD, when assign emu_logFile to it so that when I view the AVD Details it says C:\android-dev\emu_sdcard\emu_logFile against the field "SD Card"
- Here is the relevant code

```
public class ZLogger {   
  static PrintWriter zLogWriter = null;
private static void Initialize() {
    try {
        File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        if (sdDir.canWrite()) {
            :
            File logFile = new File (sdDir, VERSION.RELEASE + "_" + ".log");

            FileWriter logFileWriter = new FileWriter(logFile);

            zLogWriter = new PrintWriter(logFileWriter);

            zLogWriter.write("\n\n - " + date + " - \n");               
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("ZLogger", "Count not write to file: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

**sdDir.canWrite** returns false - please note it not the exception

from adb shell when I do ls I see sdcard as link to /mnt/sdcard. When I do ls -l /mnt here is what I see

## ls -l /mnt

ls -l /mnt
drwxr-xr-x root     system            2010-12-24 03:41 asec
drwx------ root     root              2010-12-24 03:41 secure
d--------- system   system            2010-12-24 03:41 sdcard

whereas if I go to the directory where I created emu_sdcard - I see a lock has been issued, as shown here

C:>dir android-dev\emu_sdcard
 Volume in drive C is Preload
 Volume Serial Number is A4F3-6C29

Directory of C:\android-dev\emu_sdcard

12/24/2010  03:41 AM                .
12/24/2010  03:41 AM              ..
12/24/2010  03:17 AM         8,388,608 emu_logFile
12/24/2010  03:41 AM              emu_logFile.lock
               1 File(s)      8,388,608 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  50,347,704,320 bytes free

I have looked at these and other SO questions
Android Emulator sdcard push error: Read-only file system (2)
Not able to view SDCard folder in the FileExplorer of Android Eclipse

I have added the following to AndroidManifest.xml
**uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"   **

Please let me know your thoughts - what am I missing here? Why does **canWrite** return false? What should I do to add permissions to sdcard?

Comment: I also tried sdDir.canRead - even that method returns false. BTW, I am unable to compile if I use sdDir.getToalSpace - "method getTotalSpace() is undefined for the type File"  -   The intellisense  should File methods similar to that shown here http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html. The intellisense does not match with http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html. I checked java -version the output is "1.6.0_18". I am running Android 2.2  any suggestions - please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the message in the console window which I missed all the while -
 `[2010-12-28 12:14:08 - Emulator] ### WARNING: SD Card files must be at least 9MB, ignoring 'C:\android-dev\emu_sdcard\emu_logFile'`

And the other moral of the story is - monitor the console Window too not just the LogCat window

Answer (score 1):

well - I did get it to work (i.e. canWrite returns true).

Here is what I did

- created a new SD card Image file using the following command

`C:\android-scripts>mksdcard -l Emu1GSD 1024M C:\android-dev\emu_sdcard\emu1gsd.img`
With the previous SD card image no label was used, the size was 8MB and the extension was not .img. I haven't bothered to find out which one of these is the likely reason. Also the previous image file may have been corrupt!

- the second step was to recreate a new AVD with the new SD Card Image file. Here is what the AVD looks like now
  [image]

The getTotalspace issue as was mentioned in the previous comment still exists - I will create a new question for that.